# Yfiance print only the price of a stock

Tags: python, stock, yfinance

I want to print only the price for a stock form yfinance, this is what I get/have now :

```
    ticker = "aapl"
    start = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
    data['EMA10'] = data['Close'].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
    print(data['EMA10'])
```

and this is the response :

```
Date
2022-03-04    163.169998
Name: EMA10, dtype: float64
```

I only want to print 163....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtain a `pd.Series`. To select the top-most value within that series just do `data['EMA10'][0]`.

The entire code is given below:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr

ticker = "AAPL"
start = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
data['EMA10'] = data['Close'].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()

print(data['EMA10'][0])
```

**Output:**

`163.1699981689453`